# VK api. Не получается выбрать всех пользователей среди друзей, которым не было отправленно сообщение

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Нужно выбрать из всех друзей, тех кому не было отправлено ни одного сообщения.Если делать поиск по подстроке в сообщении, то все работает, а наоборот, чтобы выбрать всех кому данное сообщение не было отправлено не получатся. Ниже привожу рабочий код, в котором находится всех пользователей которым было отправлено сообщение с текстом - "Текст для примера"
Вот код:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
/**
 * Example 2.
 * Get access token via OAuth and usage VK API.
 * @link http://vk.com/developers.php VK API
 */

error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('src/VK/VK.php');
require_once('src/VK/VKException.php');

$vk_config = array(
    'app_id'        => '******',
    'api_secret'    => '***************',
    'callback_url'  => '',
    'api_settings'  => 'messages,friends',
    'token'         => '*************************************************'
);

try {
    $vk = new VK\VK($vk_config['app_id'], $vk_config['api_secret'], $vk_config['token']);

        $access_token = $vk_config['token']."<br>";

        echo 'access token: ' . $access_token;

        $user_friends = $vk->api('friends.get', array(
            'uid'       => '*********',
            'fields'    => 'uid,first_name,last_name',
            'order'     => 'name'
        ));
        $user_send_messeges = $vk->api('messages.get', array(
            'out'             => '1',
            'count'           => '200',
            'time_offset'     => '0',
            'offset'          => '200'
        ));
        foreach ($user_send_messeges['response'] as $k => $v) {
            if (preg_match('!Текст для примера!si',$v['body'])) {
                foreach ($user_friends['response'] as $key => $value) {
                    if ($value['uid'] == $v['uid']) {
                        echo "<hr>";
                        echo $value['uid']." - ". $value['first_name']." ".$value['last_name'].": ".$v['body'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }



} catch (VK\VKException $error) {
    echo $error->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Хочу сказать, что вызывать `messages.get` наверное будет неправильным. Ведь за всё время у пользователя может быть туча разных диалогов, т.е. не только с обычными юзерами, но и с группой пользователей. Нужно, наверное, вызывать метод [messages.getHistory](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getHistory?params[user_id]=104427406&params[v]=5.53), который возвращает историю сообщений для указанного диалога. А значит мы его сможем выбрать только для друзей.

Могу предложить чуть другой подход, но который можно будет переделать под `php` код, если будет угодно.

Сам вконтакте позволяет использовать кастомный запрос [execute](https://vk.com/dev/execute) - метод, который позволяет запускать последовательность других методов, сохраняя и фильтруя промежуточные результаты. Можно воспользоваться им и составить вот такой запрос:

```
var friends = API.friends.get({fields:"first_name, last_name", count:20, offset:0}).items;

var friendsWithNoMessages = [];

var i = 0;
while (i < friends.length) { 
    var msgCount = API.messages.getHistory({user_id: friends[i]}).count;
    if (msgCount == 0) {
        friendsWithNoMessages.push(friends[i]);
    }
    i = i + 1;
}; 

return {"friends":friends, "friendsWithNoMessages" : friendsWithNoMessages};
```

Где возвращать `"friends":friends`, в принципе, не обязательно. Там лежит id друга, имя и фамилия. А вот `friendsWithNoMessages` вернет массив тех, с кем нет сообщений ни разу.

**Однако (!!!)** Т.к. у *Вконтакте* есть ограничение на количество обращений в секунду, то придется данный запрос повторить несколько раз, засыпая на некоторый интервал времени, например на 300 мсек и каждый раз при этом смещая `offset` на 20 друзей.

**Однако2 (!!!)** Если личной переписки между друзьями не было, но они переписывались в каком-нибудь групповом чате - то такой запрос, конечно, не вернет ничего.

Comment: А есть ли вариант реализовать это не на javascript, а на php?

Comment: @Вадим ну кто же запрещает?)) берете и вместо `API.friends.get` пишите `$vk->api('friends.get'` с входными данными......... аналогично с `messages.getHistory` ......я поэтому и написал что `подход, который можно будет переделать под php` ..... по сути ничего и не поменяется. всё также придется вызывать данный блок кода несколько раз, засыпая на некоторый интервал времени

Comment: а, как быть с ограничением в 200 сообщений, пытался через цикл менять значение смещения(offset), не вышло, что то делаю не так. Вот код:

`while ($user_send_messeges['response'][$i]) {
            echo $user_send_messeges['response'][$i]['uid']."<br>";
            ++$i;
            $user_send_messeges = $vk->api('messages.get', array(
            'out'             => '1',
            'count'           => '200',
            'time_offset'     => '0',
            'offset'           => $i
        ));
        }
`